# Why does this code work eventhough it has no open brace

Tags: clojure

Why does this code work?

```
(defn g []
     do (println 10) (println 20))
```

Note: There is no ( before the do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory this shouldn't even compile. The compiler ought to complain that `do` cannot be resolved since it is a special symbol not in the first position of a form.

This is a (likely unintended) consequence of using the same [BodyExpr parsing code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L5777) for both the `do` special form and the body of the `fn*` special form. When compiling a `do` special form, the leading `do` is dropped and the remaining forms compiled. Using this same parser for a function body means a single naked `do` can also appear first.

```
public static class BodyExpr implements Expr, MaybePrimitiveExpr{

    ...

    public Expr parse(C context, Object frms) {
        ISeq forms = (ISeq) frms;
        if(Util.equals(RT.first(forms), DO))
            forms = RT.next(forms);

    ....
```

You'll notice that if the `do` is repeated, this

```
(defn g [] do do (println 10) (println 20))
;=> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      Unable to resolve symbol: do in this context ...
```

does *not* compile, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. So, it is explicitly coded an exception. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tim See edit. This is a consequence (likely unintended) of using the same parser for both the `do` special form and the body of the function special form, `fn*`.

Comment: How strange... I would have expected something like:
`=> ((fn [] println println)) ;; #<core$println clojure.core$println@15d3b17>`, but this exception seems to be the case for all special forms. `((fn [] if))`, for instance, throws the same RTE.